# I wanted to call a thread function using another thread function from 2 seperate programs, and run them parallely. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, multithreading

the t1 thread continues after t2 thread dies
I wanted to run both the threads parallely, it can be interpreted as I want to send mails if certain condition triggres in an infinite loop but i dont want to pause my infinite loop whilke sending mail

#### MAIN CODE

```
import time
import threading
import snake


def inf_loop():
    x = 0
    while True:
        if x % 5 == 0:
            t2 = threading.Thread(target=snake.print_transfered_data(x), args=[x])
            t2.start()
        print(x)
        time.sleep(0.2)
        x += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=inf_loop)

    # starting thread 1

    t1.start()
```

#### SNAKE.PY

```
import time


def print_transfered_data(n):
    for x in range(0, n):
        print("second program function " + str(x))
        time.sleep(0.3)
```

Comment: And does this code not do what you want?

Comment: No, t1 thread waits until t2 thread dies, but i want to run parallely

Comment: That's because you have a typo.  In your first thread, you are not passing the `print_transfered_data` function object.  Instead, you are CALLING that function, and passing it's return value (`None`) as the thread target.  You need to remove the `(x)` so you pass the function, and don't CALL the function.